# How do you allow users to input values for your Immediacy Plugin via the Extended Tab?

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, content-management-system, immediacy

I am currently building my first Immediacy Plugin, and do not have access to any documentation at the time of writing this.

I have created a user control (single inline file, as opposed to code behind) that produces the required output. However I need a way of passing an integer specified the page creator to the control.

I've seen this done through adding the plugin to the Extended Tab of page properties.

In the past in the company I work for the way Immediacy Plugins have been implemented, has not allowed user input through the Page Properties --> Extended Tab

What is the process for making this appear in the Extended Tab? Those who have used Immediacy in the past will know what i'm referring to hopefully.

No documentation is to hand at the moment, otherwise i'm sure it would be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not required if you just want to be able to pass in a simple variable.

Just create a public property in your User Control file and assign it when you insert the control into the page.

This only works if you are inserting the User Control into the page manually and not through the Plugins menu.

Interestingly Immediacy do not provide any documentation to Developers for creating their own plugins. This is what I got from Immediacy support anyway, all they could offer was information about a course they run for developers.